# Do these encoding times seem about correct?

Tags: avconv

I'm using avconv to convert some videos, using the following commands (replacing {{inFile}} and {{outFile}}

```
avconv -xerror  -v fatal -i {{inFile}} -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v baseline -preset slower -crf 18 -strict experimental -vf "scale=trunc(oh*a/2)*2:360" {{outFile}}
avconv -xerror  -v fatal -i {{inFile}} -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v baseline -preset slower -crf 18 -strict experimental -vf "scale=trunc(oh*a/2)*2:480" {{outFile}}
avconv -xerror  -v fatal -i {{inFile}} -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v baseline -preset slower -crf 18 -strict experimental -vf "scale=trunc(oh*a/2)*2:720" {{outFile}}
avconv -xerror  -v fatal -i {{inFile}} -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v baseline -preset slower -crf 18 -strict experimental -vf "scale=trunc(oh*a/2)*2:1080" {{outFile}}
```

I'm just doing some testing on the performance, and here's some results I got.

1. 157mb 5 minute mp4 - 58 minutes
2. 70mb 5 minute mp4 - 26 minutes.

This is the first time I've done anything with encoding, and I'm just wondering if those times seem about right. There being encoded on a ubuntu VM, with 2 GB of RAM.

If you need any other info, just let me know and I'll add it.